# Connecting to OS X server with Windows 7

Tags: macos, windows, server.app

I run an OSX server in my office (Previously Mavericks now upgraded to Yosemite) and I need to allow a few Windows laptops to the server.

I have never been fully successful at doing connect to the OSX server but I have had moments when I can see and connect.  Mostly I cannot connect at all, I don't know why that is. From Windows network, I can see the OSX server however when I attempt to Authenticate it fails.

One confusing thing that happens is that windows prompts me to log in again but forces my computer name as the domain. something like \mycomputername\name

When I see this it never connects.

I don't know if there is a trick to connect from my windows laptop or if I need ot config the server differently.

Welcome any and all insights!!!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't mention what client or protocol/s you're using... could be you're talking about samba/cifs file sharing, and if so, there is an answer elsewhere on ask different (I'll try to find) that will fix your trouhle...

But I'll just throw this out there in case because I've done a lot of ARD/VNC and RDP the other way, and the issue that presents itself most (if definitely NOT a DNS issue) is that if the mac screen falls asleep, the client query for a desktop connection goes unanswered (very often), even if you check that box in the energy settings to wake for network access.

I have a couple solutions if that is what the problem is:

The simplest solution is to set the screen to never sleep, or set a hot corner in the Screen Saver preferences panel, and leave your pointer in that corner when not in use. Its recommended you enable, in the Securtiy preference panel, check on the "require password after..." (to not leave your console completely inviting to any user).

The other solution I use is to ssh into the machine and "wake it up" with a bash script that uses osascript to simulate a key press. I believe the idea originates from a Mac Hints post from a while ago, and its posted [here](http://pastebin.com/YMqWxHKp):

```
#!/bin/bash
# wake up the screen
# (will simulate pressing the cursor key)

osascript="/usr/bin/osascript"

osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 123'

exit
```

ssh in, copy into file called "wakes" on server; leave somewhere in your $PATH, chmod +x wakes, run the command, then immediately attempt connection with the desktop sharing client.

Comment: The Apple Server has SMB enabled. I'm connecting over the LAN - nothing fancy... I'm in the dark on a few things I suppose- not the strongest network guy. I have tried VPN too but for now i am just attempting to get on the server from my windows machine.  was thinking some port might not be open or there is a domain issue.   the server was given a local server name, which I can see in windows network panel. I just can't authenticate.  I know the account is good. I can authenticate from Mac.

Comment: I don't think sleep is the issue.